# How to have an email link inside a text in Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have some large texts in a Windows phone 8 app and I want there to be e-mail links inside, something like a mailto feature.
Here's a part of the code:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="μέλη ΔΕΠ">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">                     
            <Run Text="John Doe"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="503 (Building DS 126)"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="tel.:  +30 210-1234567"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="e-mail:  johndoe@uni.gr"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

I would like the "e-mail:  johndoe@uni.gr" to be clickable and open the mail app on the phone.
There are quite a few situations like this in my code with emails in much larger text and that's why I use the `<TextBlock><Run Text=".."/><LineBreak/>...` format.

Now I know I can't use a hyperlink button inside the `<Run Text=".."/>` so any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HyperlinkButton is good if you want a hyperlink in your UI, but if you want a hyperlink embedded in a run of text you should use **RichTextBox** with a **Hyperlink**:

```
<RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="John Doe" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="503 (Building DS 126)" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run Text="tel.:  +30 210-1234567" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_OnClick">e-mail:   johndoe@uni.gr</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

And then use the handler from Julien's answer:

```
    private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
        emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
        emailComposeTask.To = "johndoe@uni.gr";
        emailComposeTask.Show();
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: For some reason, `RoutedEventArgs` was causing an error when used in `shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem`.  `EventArgs` worked, though.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do the following:

Overload MapUri() as it is done for URI-Associations of an App and never worry about handling any click events anymore.

XAML:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="tel:0800-555-1234'}">call 0800-555-1234</Hyperlink>
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:you@your-domain.com'}">e-Mail you@your-domain.com</Hyperlink>
```

C# App.xaml.cs

```
 private void InitializePhoneApplication() {
```

...

```
 //get ready for URI association
 RootFrame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper();
```

}

C#

```
class AssociateioniMapper : UriMapperBase
{
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
    tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

    Uri retUri = uri;
    //handle known uri schemes
    if (uriUsesKnownScheme(uri))
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine("Known Uri scheme: " + uri.Scheme);
        NavigateConsideringKnownScheme(uri);
        retUri = null;
    }
}

private bool uriUsesKnownScheme(Uri uri)
{
        try
        {
            switch (uri.Scheme)
            {
                case "http":
                case "https":
                case "mailto":
                case "tel":
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //uri does not have a scheme
            return false;
        }

} 

private void NavigateConsideringKnownScheme(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (uri.Scheme)
            {
                case schemeHttp:
                case schemeHttps:
                    //open URI in IE
                    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
                    webBrowserTask.Uri = uri;
                    webBrowserTask.Show();
                    break;
                case schemeMailto:
                    //initiate eMail task
                    if (! string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.Query))
                        handleMailtoUrl_Query(uri.Query);
                    else
                        handleMailtoUrl_To(uri.OriginalString.Replace("mailto:", string.Empty));
                    break;
                case schemeTel:
                    //initiate phonecall task
                    handleTel(uri.PathAndQuery);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }   

    private void handleTel(string parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            string p = parameter as string;

            string number = p;
            string displayName = string.Empty;

            number = Regex.Replace(number, "[^+0-9]", "");

            startPhoneCall(number, displayName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void startPhoneCall(string number, string displayName)
    {
        try
        {
            PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();

            phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = number;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName))
            {
                phoneCallTask.DisplayName = displayName;
            }

            phoneCallTask.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(LocalizationHelper.GetString("ContactPhonecallError"));
        }
    }

    private void handleMailtoUrl_Query(string query)
    {
       //handle subject, to, body and other parameters if required
    }

    private void handleMailtoUrl_To(string to)
    {
        try
        {
            EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

            emailComposeTask.To = to;

            emailComposeTask.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an HyperLinkButton :

```
<HyperlinkButton Name="emailLink" Content="johndoe@uni.gr" Click="EmailLink_Click" />
```

and in EmailLink_Link, you can launch the EmailComposeTask (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003(v=vs.105).aspx)

```
private void EMailLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
  emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
  emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
  emailComposeTask.To = emailLink.Content;
  emailComposeTask.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even easier:

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="yourname@yourdomain.com" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"/>
```

Click event handler:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:yourname@yourdomain.com"));
}
```

Besides opening your email app, there's a lot more you can do with the Launcher: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx