# How to handle subtext Tap?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, textblock

In Windows Phone (on both Windows Phone 7.1 and Windows Phone 8), in a block of text with wrapping I want a subtext to be underlined and clickable. However, Runs in TextBlock/RichTextBox don't have any events. Using WrapPanel of WPToolkit I could achieve the desired wrapping by putting each words in a separate TextBlock, but i loose the ability to set TextAlignment to Justify. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="I have a paragraph consisting of multiple lines that I want to be neatly wrapped with just one word that I'll be able to "/>
    <Run TextDecorations="Underline">tap</Run>
</TextBlock>

<toolkit:WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="I "/>
    <TextBlock Text="have "/>
    <TextBlock Text="a paragraph "/>
    <TextBlock Text="consisting "/>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="able to"/>
    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Tap="HandleLinkTap" Text="tap"/>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148602/546896  solves your problem?
I know little hackish way but still see if it works.

```
<RichTextBox TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="I have a paragraph consisting of multiple lines that I want to be   neatly wrapped with just one word that I'll be able to " />
        <Hyperlink Click="HandleLinkTap">Tap</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```